# replace font-awesome icons in function file

Tags: php, function, replace, font-awesome

i have a function in my function.php using a font-awesome to display icon on my site, but i need to change this icons to my custom images i've tried many ways but it didn't work anyway, here's my code in my function.php.

```
function getRankIcon($rank){
    $user = array(
        'user_bot'=> 0,
        'user_role'=> 0,
        'user_rank'=> $rank,
    );
    return rankIcon($user);
}
function rankIcon($list, $type = 1){
    global $lang;
    if(isBot($list['user_bot'])){
        return curRanking($lang['user_bot'], 'ico_bot', 'android');
    }
    else if($list['user_role'] > 0 && $list['user_rank'] < 8 && $type == 2){
        switch($list['user_role']){
            case 5:
                return curRanking($lang['r_admin'], 'ico_radmin', 'legal');
            case 4:
                return curRanking($lang['r_mod'], 'ico_rmod', 'legal');
        }
    }
    else {
        switch($list['user_rank']){
            case 0:
                return curRanking($lang['guest'], 'ico_guest', 'paw');
            case 1:
                return curRanking($lang['user'], 'ico_user', 'user');
            case 2:
                return curRanking($lang['vip'], 'ico_vip', 'diamond');
            case 8:
                return curRanking($lang['mod'], 'ico_mod', 'shield');
            case 9:
                return curRanking($lang['admin'], 'ico_admin', 'star');
            case 10:
                return curRanking($lang['owner'], 'ico_owner', 'trophy');
            default:
                return curRanking($lang['user'], 'ico_user', 'user');
        }
    }
}
function curRanking($txt, $color, $icon){
    return '<i title="' . $txt . '" class="' . $color . ' fa fa-' . $icon . '"></i>';
}
```

in this line.

```
return curRanking($lang['owner'], 'ico_owner', 'trophy');
```

'trophy' is font-awesome icon i need to replace it with image, so what i have to do now?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the tour and read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: It's a bad practice/anti pattern to use "magic numbers": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)

Comment: you should change curRanking behavior...  we need to see how it works

Comment: actually this is a chat script so i think it won't work here, i just wanna know if there's any way or any code to replace this icons with images. :/